# Combining Rails and React on same Heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, heroku

I've recently deployed a `ReactJS` application on `Heroku` and everything went fine there.
But now I'm trying to deploy my `RailsAPI` app on there too, but everything I do I get errors, it's something with the `git push` that don't work.
He always says : `hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind`

I suppose this is because there is already my `ReactJS` app on there? When I force `push` this happens :

```
App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/nodejs.tgz
```

How can I run `ReactJS` along with `RailsAPI` on the same `Heroku` app? I've been searching and read a few stackoverflow posts but I can't seem to find anything similar to this...
I followed some tutorials but I don't get how they do it.

I'm using 2 different folders (and 2 different git repos) for the projects, so `RailsAPI` is seperated from `ReactJS`

My `buildpacks` for this project :

```
=== neighborapp-oc Buildpack URLs
1. heroku/nodejs
2. heroku/ruby
```

Comment: You could deploy the React app and Rails API on two different heroku instances. Here is a tutorial of how you could do that. https://gist.github.com/MJeorrett/a42db098b32a51949c05ee36fd49c91e Otherwise you need to use multiple buildpacks for your heroku app, supporting both nodejs and rails, see here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app

Comment: @Pierre I already added 2 `buildpacks` but it still don't seem to work, I added them in the question

Comment: Heroku uses a single git repository to manage a Heroku app, so you only need one. Maybe you could find more help here https://medium.com/@bruno_boehm/reactjs-ruby-on-rails-api-heroku-app-2645c93f0814

Comment: So I have to combine my 2 folders then? Because right now the 2 projects have a different git for each one. Or at least have a git repo with 2 folders in it.

Comment: @Pierre I tried by doing everything with 1 git repo, setting 2 buildpacks but I have the same error. It says that there is no default language if I remove the buildpacks, I suppose it's because there is `javascript` and `rails` in the same repo

Comment: Simply combining the two folders won't work, since both folders have their own git repos. You should add the code from one repo to the other (the one connected to the heroku app). You cant remove the buildpacks, you need both of them.

Comment: I created a single repo with the 2 projects in it. And even with the 2 buildpacks, it tries to apply the nodejs buildpack to rails as well, and that gives me an error.

Comment: I'll maybe just try to create 2 different apps, will be easier I think

Comment: Just because I think it is an extremely cool project you should checkout [`hyperstack`](https://hyperstack.org/). This provides ruby DSL based rails/react interaction and offers a full tutorial on how to deploy to heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but in my opinion there is no reason not to create two separate apps, and then just direct your rails API calls in your frontend to the URL created by the rails heroku app. It works well in my experience. :)